# How to build DataTable that I can fill text in?

Tags: flutter, dart, web, web-applications, datatable

I want to build Table that I can insert data (text) into the table similar to this

[image]

but!!!! I want the empty table that I can fill text in the table, not fetch form list

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement isn't entirely clear, but please review the following code. It initializes the 'tableData' variable as a 2D list containing 3 rows and 3 columns, initially populated with empty strings.

```
List<List<String>> tableData = List.generate(3, (_) => List.filled(3, ''));
```

This code creates a table layout with borders using the Table widget. Each cell in the table is a TextFormField widget allowing text input, and onChanged updates the tableData list with the entered text.

```
Table(
        border: TableBorder.all(),
        children: List.generate(
          tableData.length,
          (rowIndex) => TableRow(
            children: List.generate(
              tableData[rowIndex].length,
              (colIndex) => Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  initialValue: tableData[rowIndex][colIndex],
                  onChanged: (text) {
                    setState(() {
                      tableData[rowIndex][colIndex] = text;
                    });
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    hintText: 'Enter text',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
```

Comment: I mean the table that I can fill text in there

Comment: https://prnt.sc/Y3dYnl2UHzIl Please check screenshot.